# confusion writing git filter-branch to move all files in to subdirectory

Tags: git, repository, git-filter-branch

I believe that git filter-branch can allow me to do this, but I can't figure out if i need to use --subdirectory-filter or if I need to use an index filter.

But, let's say I have a repository called repo, and the structure looks something like:

```
repo/fileA
repo/fileB
repo/dir1/fileC
```

What I want to do is move everything in to a directory called dir2 so the result is:

```
repo/dir2/fileA
repo/dir2/fileB
repo/dir2/dir1/fileC
```

I want to use filter-branch to make it look like ever since the birth of this repository, everything was always done in dir2.  Is it more appropriate to use a subdirectory file or index filter to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tree filter. Something like the following should work:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'test -e fileA && mkdir dir2 && mkdir dir2/dir1 && mv fileA fileB dir2/ && mv dir1/fileC dir2/dir1/ || echo "no op"' HEAD
```

However, this assumes that fileA, fileB and fileC were added at the same time (since we use test -e for fileA) and that might not be the case. If that's not the case you have to do several sweeps for each of the files.

Comment: This worked for me, just putting `git mv * dir2/` as the move command

Answer (score 2):

With Git 2.24, [**`git filter-branch` is deprecated**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

The equivalent would be, using [**`newren/git-filter-repo`**](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), and its [example section](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES):

```
cd repo
git filter-repo --to-subdirectory-filter dir2
```

That will rename any folder, including `/` to `dir2`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a tree filter.

- subdirectory filter is designed to go the other way (move an existing directory to the root of the repository, ignoring the rest).
- index filter is designed to modify the index without checking things out, but `git mv` doesn't have an option to only work on the index, so you probably do actually need a checkout to work with.