# Error when changing git commit author with filter-branch

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-filter-branch, refs

I'm trying to change the author for my git commits as I forgot to update my global e-mail. I used this code below to change it (with my own details).

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
OLD_EMAIL="OldEmail"
CORRECT_NAME="new name"
CORRECT_EMAIL="new email" 
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

The script runs but then says:

```
Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
Could not rewrite refs/heads/master
```

I'm a bit of a git newbie, can't find this error anywhere is it something to do with the user? I'm trying to run this through source tree is it something I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: The "could not rewrite" case usually only occurs if you did git operations as another user-*ID* (so that part of your repository is owned by someone else).  For instance, if you log in as user `A`, and try to filter-branch a repository owned by user `B`, you could get this; or if you ran `sudo` to do some git operation, when you should not have.  You can probably get this by setting a bad umask as well.

Comment: I thought it could be something to do with that. I'm using SourceTree and my default user information is the author to my commits, which helpfully isn't an e-mail address at all. How would I log in as this "default user" if it doesn't exist?

Comment: It sounds like you're using some kind of GUI, and perhaps Windows, which throws pretty much everything I know out.  If this were command line Linux/BSD/Mac, I could perhaps be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you now have a better alternative:

- perform a filter on a freshly cloned repository
- *do not* used `git filter-branch` anymore, which [is declared (as of Git 2.24, Q4 2019) as somewhat deprecated.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309)

Use instead its possible successor: [**`newren/git-filter-repo`**](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (in Python), and its [example section](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES):

```
cd repo
git filter-repo --mailmap my-mailmap
```

with `my-mailmap`:

```
Correct Name <correct@email.com> <old@email.com>
```

That would replace the author name and email of any commit done by anyone with `<old@email.com>`

See [`gitmailmap` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmailmap#_examples) for examples of the mapping file syntax.

---

Another possible cause for "`Could not rewrite`" has been cleaned up with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021).

See [commit 42efa12](https://github.com/git/git/commit/42efa1231aee85932058cc6d1571ab4ceb3e7eff), [commit 98fe9e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/98fe9e666fe4a595cf5396fd8d5c57b380c782b2), [commit 6d875d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d875d19fd7346f4a6dc47d2a1363db91e9643d5) (10 Mar 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d4bda9b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d4bda9b0451fcc7f3fd485be2048cb731f7072ce), 22 Mar 2021)</sup>

> ### [`filter-branch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/98fe9e666fe4a595cf5396fd8d5c57b380c782b2): drop multiple-ancestor warning
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> When a ref maps to a commit that is neither rewritten nor kept by filter-branch (e.g., because it was eliminated by rev-list's pathspec selection), we rewrite it to its nearest ancestor.
>
> Since the initial commit in [6f6826c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f6826c52bb751450e2bfa28f07c817dfa5802d6) ("Add `git-filter-branch`", 2007-06-03, Git v1.5.3-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f2890acd999e63892d0b5b401e70bdaefe3ba51)), we have warned when there are multiple such ancestors in the map file.
> However, the warning code is impossible to trigger these days.
> Since [a0e4639](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a0e46390d397e71182e42930b98b6b59a1a84898) ("`filter-branch`: fix ref rewriting with `--subdirectory-filter`", 2008-08-12, Git v1.6.1-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/01914577ed42498d9e268684949d699e0272e964)), we find the ancestor using "`rev-list -1`", so it can only ever have a single value.
>
> This code is made doubly confusing by the fact that we append to the map file when mapping ancestors.
> However, this can never yield multiple values because:
>
> - we explicitly check whether the map already exists, and if so, do nothing (so our "append" will always be to a file that does not exist)
> - even if we were to try mapping twice, the process to do so is deterministic.
>   I.e., we'd always end up with the same ancestor for a given sha1.
>   So warning about it would be pointless; there is no ambiguity.
>
> So swap out the warning code for a BUG (which we'll simplify further in the next commit).
> And let's stop using the append operator to make the ancestor-mapping code less confusing.

No more

> WARNING: '$ref' was rewritten into multiple commits:"
> WARNING: Ref '$ref' points to the first one now
> Could not rewrite $ref

Instead:

> Fatal: BUG: multiple ancestors in map file?