# Git - Remove All of a Certain Type of File from the Repository

Tags: git, git-rm

How do I remove all of a certain type of file from the Repository? I'm using

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached **/*.jar'
```

Either git is not expanding globs, or it isn't expanding `**` in the way I'm expecting.

Comment: Do you want to remove them from the index or form the repo? filter-branch will "clean" your repo

Comment: @CodeWizard You're right, I had misstated the question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached **/*.jar'
```

should work, but it's a bit silly because git globs (`*`) match path separators. So, `**/*.jar` is equivalent to `*.jar`.

This also means that `*/a*.jar` matches `dir1/abc/dir2/log4j.jar`. If you want to match something like `**/a*.jar` (all jars whose name starts with `a` in any directory), you should use find. Here's a command to remove any jars whose names start with `a` or `b`, and any jars in `dir1/dir2`, and any .txt file in any directory:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached "*.txt" "dir1/dir2/*.jar" $(find -type f -name "a*.jar" -o -name "b*.jar")'
```

References: `pathspec` section of `git help glossary`.

Answer (score 26):

You simply have to run this in order to remove all your jars from the index:

```
git rm -r --cached **/*.jar
```

Run this command from your root directory of the project and it will clean up and will remove all your file only from the staging area.

Comment: What expands `**`? Bash (or some other shell) or git? Since `index-filter` doesn't check out the code, bash expansion is not helpful here.

Comment: If I understand properly, `**` is not necessary there because in git, `*` matches path separators :-o. (see `pathspec` under `git help glossary`.)

Answer (score 24):

With Git 2.24 (Q4 2019), [**`git filter-branch` is deprecated**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

The equivalent would be, using [**`newren/git-filter-repo`**](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), and its [example section](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES):

```
cd repo
git filter-repo --path-glob '*.jar' --invert-paths
```

That will remove any jar file from the repository history.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way I've found is to use the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)

The instructions on the project page are clear. The command you would use is something like:

```
bfg --delete-files "*.jar"  my-repo.git
```

BFG will clean the history of the repo of all files ending in the .jar extension. You can then inspect the result before pushing it back to the server.

Comment: on a 700G .git folder, BFG barfs with org.eclipse.jgit.errors.LargeObjectException: baa7b692c1a57f577770b6eefab3e8eb16e10d54 exceeds size limit

Comment: @zumalifeguard have you tried this?:

`--massive-non-file-objects-sized-up-to <size>
                           increase memory usage to handle over-size Commits, Tags, and Trees that are up to X in size (eg '10M')`

Comment: It may be of interest that bfg is available for mac via brew (`brew install bfg`) and WinX via choco (`choco install bfg-repo-cleaner`).

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not a git command, but for those who are interested in how to accomplish that on linux machine, you can use

```
git ls-files | grep "\.sh$" | { while IFS= read -r line; do git rm --cached "$line"; done }
```

Here we list all of files in git index and forward that output to grep command to filter only `.sh` files and than for each file we perform `git rm --cached <file>`.