# How to disable Git-commit with specific packages and files inside AndroidStudio?

Tags: git, android-studio, version-control, git-commit, ignore

### The Problem

I had a lot of files autogenerated by Android studio after I build the project, so when I try to `commit` the project, the commit section is full of files I didn't want to `commit` or `push` to the repo.

[image]

**How I can tell `Git` to don't care about these files and didn't commit or push them?**

### What I try

I try to add the packages dir in the `.gitignor` file, but it seems nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked, but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-can-i-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitign)

Answer (score 1):

While a `git rm --cached -r -- *.dex` should be enough, don't forget it will only delete those files from the current commit.

If they are big, and should never have been committed, you would need to [remove them from the full history of commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58252098/6309) (assuming you are the only one working on this repository, or assuming you can warn your colleague about the impending `git push --force`)

Using [`newren/git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo)

```bash
cd repo
git filter-repo --path-glob '*.dex' --invert-paths
```

Again, if those files are small, and with a limited history, a simple `git rm --cached` is enough.