# Git refuses to see my commits as mine - must I / can I change with git command line?

Tags: git, github

I have a pull request that gives the following Github error:

lb1programmer seems not to be a GitHub user. You need a GitHub account to be able to sign the CLA. If you have already a GitHub account, please add the email address used for this commit to your account.
You have signed the CLA already but the status is still pending? Let us recheck it.

Now I have added the email to Github, but it seems the email does not show on the [commit](https://github.com/elementor/elementor/pull/9241/commits)? Do I have to somehow recreate the branch or change the history with a git command to the normal username... just because the computer I happen to work on has an old Sourceforge username set up?

Answer (score 0):

Check the section "[Commits are not linked to any user](https://help.github.com/en/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user#commits-are-not-linked-to-any-user)"

If you have committed with the wrong config user.name/user.email in place, you would need to [filter your branch to change the author](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58263677/6309), and force push your PR branch.