# Importing git project to gitlab account from a different mail address

Tags: git, gitlab

I set up a gitlab account with mail address one.

I had setup git account with mail address two, and made a lot of push on it for the last few months.

Now I'm improting those project to the gitlab account.
I managed to do so by changing the origin of the git project and changing the upstream to point toward the gitlab repo.

My issue comes from the fact that those commits does not appear in the gitlab timeline.

To solve the issue I have :

- Add the git mail address to the gitlab account
- Place the new project (comming from git) in public

gitlab see the commits made with both my addresses as coming from the same user, however, still does not display those commits in my profil timeline.

Does anyone know why ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GitLab would only see those commits as "you" (meaning your GitLab account) from your main email address declared on said account.

You might need (if nobody cloned your repository) to use [`newren/git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) to change your email address on *all* your commits in order to solve this.
See "[How to change commit author for multiple commits using filter branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58263677/6309)".

Comment: thanks for your answer. The problem still remain, even if I change the commit author, gitlab does not show the commits on the profil timeline.

Comment: @brn The commut author name does not matter: the commit author *email* does: change it locally (with `git-filter-repo`), force push, and your commits will be properly attributed to your GitLab account.