# How to switch github account and retrospectively update commit history?

Tags: git, github

I have made several commits using a GitHub account on a private repository. I would however like to switch my github account and also transfer the commit history to the new account as-if I was always using the new account. Is there a way to accomplish this in GitHub?
I read about [transferring repository](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/transferring-a-repository) but my the repository is not owned by me and also doesn't provide an option to *transfer*.

Answer (score 1):

If you can clone the repository, you need then to use [newren/git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) in order to rewrite the author from your old account to your new account.

See "[How to change commit author for multiple commits using filter branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58263677/6309)" and
"[`git filter-repo` / User and email based filtering](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_user_and_email_based_filtering)"

```
git filter-repo --mailmap my-mailmap
```

with `my-mailmap`:

```
Correct Name <correct@email.com> <old@email.com>
```

Then you can create a new empty repository on GitHub, and push everything to it:

```
git remote set-url https://github.com/<me>/newRepo>
git push --mirror
```