# Git Subdirectory Filter with tags

Tags: git, split, git-tag, git-filter-branch

I am attempting to split a large repo into multiple smaller ones. The goal is to split a folder and retain the tags in the process.

I have tried:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter my-folder develop
```

This correctly place `my-folder` at the root of the new project, and retained the tags. However checking out a tag resulted in seeing the entire old directory structure within the new repo.

So I tried:

```
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter my-folder -- --branches=develop --tags
```

This results in the develop branch being there with the old directory structure, **BUT** when I checkout a tag I see the subdirectory correctly filtered to the root! So the tags are correct but not the develop branch. Basically it has the opposite problem to the first method.

I am at a loss as to why the second method did not work. I would really appreciate any pointers!

EDIT:

Trying this now:

```
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter my-folder -- --all
```

Was hesitant as I expect that this will take quite a bit longer.
This did take longer, but it mostly worked.
What did not work? Well the older tags in which the folder had not yet been created were left in the repo and when checked out contained the full (very) old directory structure. I had to grep and delete all these tags.
Still the repo is not as small as I wuold have expected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in "[Git commands that could break/rewrite the history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309)", the old git filter-branch command is slowly being deprecated.

Using the new [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), that would be:

```
 git filter-repo --path my-folder/ --to-subdirectory-filter / -- refs develop
```

Then push that one branch to a new empty Git repository.

That should move the relevant tags correctly.

Comment: I will give it a go presently.

Comment: I can only access 2.22.0. Do you know if it works with that version?

Comment: Indeed works with 2.22.0 but I am being hit with a bug related to python not being able to process non unicode strings (or something to that effect). I am in a relatively restrictive environment and am not able to fire up a linux image to solve this for myself unfortunately. This is on a git-for-windows install

Comment: @Dennis OK. Note: for Git for Windows, you can install any version you want (no elevation privilege required). However, Git 2.24 does have a bug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59383810/6309

Comment: going to accept yours as the answer at this stage. It looks like I would need to get `2.23` (thanks for pointing out that bug!) as well as another version of filter-repo. I will give it a go again.