# git filter-repo: can it be used on a specific branch?

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

I'm reading about what `git filter-repo` can do because I want to do a small experiment with it.... I have this repo where I only want to get the history of one directory from, say.... master..... but I don't want to work on master. I would like to create a new branch, say `filter-repo-test` and let `git filter-repo` run its magic on this branch alone. I'm reading the manual but I don't see an option to specify only a given branch. Is it possible?

https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ['Miscellaneous Options](https://refined-github-html-preview.kidonng.workers.dev/newren/git-filter-repo/raw/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_miscellaneous_options)' includes `--refs`

--refs <refs+>

> Limit history rewriting to the specified refs. Implies `--partial`.
> In addition to the normal caveats of `--partial` (mixing old and new history, no automatic remapping of `refs/remotes/origin/*` to `refs/heads/*`, etc.), this also may cause problems for pruning of degenerate empty merge commits when negative revisions are specified.

And... it will move tags, as I documented in "[Git Subdirectory Filter with tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58461146/6309)", which does uses `--refs`, as an example.

---

As [Ryan Wheale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264794/ryan-wheale) notes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59315574/git-filter-repo-can-it-be-used-on-a-specific-branch/59316302?noredirect=1#comment132416104_59316302):

> You should be able to use the branch name to limit the filtering to the branch.
> Again, take note of the caveats of `--partial`.
>
> ```
> --refs filter-repo-test
> ```

Comment: Just a note for others: you should be able to use the branch name to limit the filtering to the branch. Again, take note of the caveats of `--partial`: `--refs filter-repo-test`

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just found it. It was right under my nose. It is defined with `--refs`