# Understanding why git-filter-branch is not cleaning my history

Tags: bash, git, shell, unix

I used gitleaks to check for leaked secret in my repos history. When I ran the following command and forced the push

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
  'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch terra/fixtures.go' \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

it seemed to work, except I noticed the following:

```
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/automate_tests' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/ethRawTransaction' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/feature/177/leave-bastion' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/feature/FAQ' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/mjolnir' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/tmp' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/automate_tests' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/bug/0.0.11-beta-fix' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/bug/bastion-ssh' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/bug/fix-examples-merge' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/develop' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/ethRawTransaction' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/feature/168/auto-ssh-to-bastion' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/feature/169/ethstats_for_pantheon' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/feature/175/ssh-to-certain-nodes' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/feature/176/tagging-nodes-to-ips' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/feature/177/leave-bastion' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/feature/FAQ' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/feature/README' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/mjolnir' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/tmp' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/0.0.4' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/20190820141131-866368a' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/20190820142202-bd96767' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/20190820143451-fc7f46a' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/20190820143903-832818a' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/20190820150546-05e3105' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/20190820154631-da0cdab' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/20190820160956-047caa6' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/20190820162243-a300fa5' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/20190820170410-47f8878' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/untagged-f148f02c4d71ed0bea99' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/v.0.0.1' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/v0.0.1' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/v0.0.1-alpha' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/v0.0.10' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/v0.0.11-beta' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/v0.0.14' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/v0.0.3-alpha' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/v0.0.4-chaos-poc' is unchanged
```

As a result, the number of leaks do not seem to be going down.

I am confused as to why this is happening and would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The refs that `git filter-branch` reports as unchanged did not have a file named `terra/fixtures.go` anywhere in their histories.  Filter-branch informs you that although you asked it to update these branch names to point to any copied commits, no commits were actually copied in the process.

It might be interesting to find a list of reachable commit hash IDs that *do* have such a file, and then run `git branch --contains` on such hash IDs.  See below.

#### Which commits contain file *F?*

Note that this is a different answer to a different question.  It's also not looking for commits in which some path name was *modified*, but rather for commits in which some path name *exists at all*.

We start by using `git rev-list` to list all commits:

```
git rev-list --all |
```

The output from `git rev-list` is simply a list of every commit hash ID that is *reachable from* the named revision(s).  In this case, `--all` names all branches and tags, along with other refs such as `refs/stash`, but not any reflog entries.

Then, for each commit listed, we want to test whether this commit contains the named file(s).  At this point you generally want a lot of programmability.  For instance, suppose the file name is `a/b/c.txt`.  Do you want to also find `A/B/C.TXT`?  If you're on Windows or MacOS, you might.  If you're on Linux, probably not.  Or, maybe you want to find *any* file whose name starts or ends with some pattern.

What we'll do here is use `git ls-tree -r`, which lists out all the file names, and then run them through a search-and-status command such as `grep`.  Note that `grep` searches for *regular expressions*, not glob patterns, so `a*b` means *zero or more `a` characters followed by a `b` character* and will match the strings "abc.txt", "b", "flobby", and so on: these all have zero or more `a`s followed by a `b`.  We'll let the actual matched names show through, so that a human can apply further filtering if needed:

```
git rev-list --all |
    while read hash; do
        git ls-tree -r $hash > /tmp/files
        if grep -s 'terra/fixtures\.go' /tmp/files; then
            echo "commit ${hash} :"
            grep 'terra/fixtures\.go' /tmp/files
        fi
    done
rm /tmp/files
```

The output of this set of commands—which you probably should put in a file, and which I have not tested and might contain errors—is a list of commit hash IDs suitable for extraction but also followed by the matched names: you should probably discard matches for, e.g., `sputerra/fixtures.gobble`.

(It's possible to write fancier `grep` patterns that match more exactly.  In this case, *anchoring* the regular expression with `^` and `$` would suffice.  In more complicated cases, more complicated regular expressions are required.  I leave this to whoever is using the code.)

Having obtained hash IDs—run the above and redirect to a file, clean up the file, and then extract the more interesting hash IDs—you can then do:

```
git branch --contains <hash>
```

on any given commit hash to see which branches contain that particular commit.  Note that there may be zero or more branches containing any given commit.  For (much) more about that, read and understand [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

Comment: Thanks for your help! can you please explain how to do `It might be interesting to find a list of reachable commit hash IDs that do have such a file, and then run git branch --contains on such hash IDs.)`

Answer (score 1):

Try with double quotes

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
  "git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch 'terra/fixtures.go'" \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Answer (score 1):

Try instead the [new `git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), which [will replace the old `git filter-branch` or BFG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309)

```
git filter-repo --use-base-name --path terra/fixtures.go --invert-paths
```

By default, this new command works on all branches.
Then a `git push --all --force`, to override the history of the remote repository.

Comment: Thanks ! I got this: `git: 'filter-repo' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`; `git --version
git version 2.21.0 (Apple Git-122)`

Comment: @SamuelDare Yes: you need to install it first in your PATH: https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/master/INSTALL

Comment: Tried used the Makefile i.e make install but get this : `samueldare$ make installmkdir -p man1
git show docs:man1/git-filter-repo.1 >Documentation/man1/git-filter-repo.1
/bin/sh: Documentation/man1/git-filter-repo.1: No such file or directory
make: *** [Documentation/man1/git-filter-repo.1] Error 1`

Comment: @SamuelDare No make required. Clone the repo and add the folder to your PATH.

Comment: Thanks!! now i get this `Error: need a version of git whose diff-tree command has the --combined-all-paths option`

Comment: @SamuelDare What version of Git are you using?

Comment: git --version git version 2.21.0 (Apple Git-122)

Comment: upgraded my git and "got it to work" but the commands you gave me seems to just delete everything in the folders including the `.git file`

Comment: @SamuelDare Can you try again with `--invert-paths` added (I have edited the answer). See https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES