# Removing a subfolder of repo 1 to make new repo 2 (bitbucket repos)

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket git repo `repo1` containing (among other folders and subfolders) a subfolder `repo1/path/to/mysubfolder`. The architecture of `mysubfolder` is

```
\mysubfolder
    folder1
    ...
    foldern
    file1
    ...
    filep
```

and the path to `mysubfolder` contains spaces.
I have an empty bitbucket git repo `repo2`. I would like to :

- remove `mysubfolder` from `repo1` (history include)
- make `mysubfolder` contains be the contains of `repo2`, that is, that the architecture of `repo2` be the same as the one of `repo1`
- make `repo2`'s history equal to `mysubfolder`'s history.

A complication though : `mysubfolder`'s history is huge and contain a small hundred of commits that concern `mysubfolder` but also files/folders not in `mysubfolder`'. (That is, does not only contain "pure" `mysubfolder` commits.)

Comment: Thoroughly applying https://stackoverflow.com/a/359759/1581875 made my day.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and have a look at the new [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), which will replace [BFG and `git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

It does offer filtering/renaming options which would enable you to cleanup the history of your repository from a specific subfolder.

Comment: Given an "unpure" commit, is it possible to split it into a pure commit and a commit that does not concern `mysubfolder` ?

Comment: @ujsgeyrr1f0d0d0r0h1h0j0j_juj The filter-repo script will operate on the content, so it will change a commit to rewrite it without mysubfolder, leaving it as "pure".