# Transfering ownership of bitbucket repository

Tags: git, react-native, bitbucket

I am responsible for taking over a react-native application as a freelancer from a previous freelancer.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Once the previous freelancer transfers the ownership of the repo to me, should I then change passwords related to database, API keys etc?

Answer (score 0):

> should I then change passwords related to database, API keys etc?

Only if those credentials were part of the repository itself, in which case:

- not only should you change them post-haste
- but you should make sure to purge the history of the repository of said credentials (using the new tool [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) which [replaces  BFG and `git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).
- and establish third-party external referentials to store/access those credentials ([like a Hashicorp Vault](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/continuously-integrating-policy-into-vault/))

If said credentials were not part of the Git repository, then rotating/refreshing them is orthogonal of any ownership transfer.
It is simply a good practice, but not tied to the repository itself.