# What happens to other branches when I use BFG Repo-Cleaner on master

Tags: git, github, repository, bfg-repo-cleaner

I'm trying to use [this](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) tool to shrink my `.git` folder size which is 3.1GB right now. Code is under 100MB. This repo is very old and has many branches ~250.

If I use this tool on master branch, what will happen to other branches? It mentions:

> By default the BFG doesn't modify the contents of your latest commit
>   on your master (or 'HEAD') branch, even though it will clean all the
>   commits before it.

So I assume it would break up things in other branches? Or it doesn't break latest commits on other branches? What I want to achieve is as long as other branches' latest commit is safe, I'm fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is precisely what the new tool [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), which [replaces  BFG and `git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309), avoids: it does rewrite all the way to the latest commit.
See its [user manual](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html)

```
git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M --refs master
```

It automatically removes old cruft and repacks the repository for the user after filtering (unless overridden); this simplifies things for the user, helps avoid mixing old and new history together.

As show here (applied only on `master`), that won't touch the other branches, but yes, the new `master` branch might  no longer share any common history with other branches.

Comment: Thanks for answer! What if I want to apply `--strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M` to all branch. Would it keep it latest commits of all branch? (Hoping I won't ruin other branch's latest fixes.)

Comment: Just remove the refs part: do it on a local clone copy, that way you can evaluate the result and see if it is satisfactory.