# Why in my project git file size very large?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I use git for my project. We develop this project about 2 year. Now this .git file is 908,3 MB.
I think this size not normal so i want to decrease file size of git. So how to fix them? thank you.

[image: You can see git file size on this photo.]

Comment: I don't want to lose my code history, there must be a way :)

Comment: Do you have binary artifacts in your git repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and purge the history of the repository for large file: use the new tool [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) which [replaces  BFG and `git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

```
git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M
```

Check the size of the `.git` folder then.
Make sure those large files were not needed in your repo history.

Note: if you get the following error message when running the above-mentioned commands:

```
Error: need a version of `git` whose `diff-tree` command has the `--combined-all-paths` option`
```

it means you have to [update `git`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33618/16704).

Comment: When i tried it say that "Error: need a version of git whose diff-tree command has the --combined-all-paths option"

Comment: I updated my git version after that it worked. If i choose 1m,  could it be an error? ( Also this code doesn't not change git file so i can't push on my repo)

Comment: @AliYaman 1m is fine: make sure is does not delete too much. Clone the resulting local repo again to see if the end result looks fine. And `git push --force` of you want to update your remote repository.

Comment: I tried it and really I research it but i can't push it. Always said that "

Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository using

    git remote add <name> <url>

and then push using the remote name

    git push <name>" ( note : I tried in my branch )

Comment: @AliYaman Regarding pushing, you just need to add the URL of your existing remote repo (if you are sure the history you have locally is correct), then `git push -f -u origin master`