# Git fetch - large number of objects, slow download

Tags: git, gitlab

When I run `git fetch production` to fetch objects from my remote repository hosted on Gitlab, I get the following in my terminal -

```
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4895/4895), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (515/515), done.
Receiving objects:  25% (11199/44589), 476.81 MiB | 3.42 MiB/s
```

This seems to take forever, because each object seems to be large in size.

The fun part is - I've absolutely no clue which are these objects; because I've double-checked my local repository; and all I have is Laravel Framework, with my custom code; and no big packages. I'd estimate max size of my repository should not be greater than 200 - 300 MB.

Is there any way to troubleshoot this? It's driving me nuts!

Update: While I was composing this question, the terminal threw the following -

```
Receiving objects: 100% (44589/44589), 1.14 GiB | 3.39 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (28324/28324), done.
```

The objects size seems to have gone down from 44589 -> 28324. Can someone help me figure out what's going on and how can I speed up my git pulls and git fetches?

Comment: Does your repository include submodule(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you ca  quickly [list the large objects in your repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42544963/6309).

Second, you can then proceed and delete some of those object in the *history* of your repository (meaning your current checked out working tree might be small, but large objects might have been committed, then removed, and their presence is still felt when cloning a repository)
You would need to [use `git filter-repo`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59710907/6309).

---

On the server side:

See [GitLab 14.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/11/22/gitlab-14-5-released/#git-fetch-resource-optimizations) (November 2021)

> ### Git fetch resource optimizations
>
> Git fetch resource optimizations
>
> We improved the [performance of traffic between Workhorse and Gitaly](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/scalability/-/issues/1193#note_731767857), resulting in `git fetch` now using fewer GitLab server resources.
>
> This change can cause issues on self-managed GitLab if a gRPC proxy is deployed between Workhorse and Gitaly.
>
> If you deployed a gRPC proxy between Workhorse and Gitaly, Workhorse can no longer connect. As a workaround, disable the temporary [`workhorse_use_sidechannel` feature flag](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/feature_flags.html#enable-or-disable-the-feature).
> If you need a proxy between Workhorse and Gitaly, use a TCP proxy.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/#1450) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/scalability/-/issues/1301).

Comment: That command did the job. I got a large number of entries in following format: `63e9a6bdd152 379839 public/apps/downloads/CrazyEngineers-6363-software-companies-placement-papers-huge-collection-6ZvE1l.zip` . If I run the `git filter-repo` command, do I need to commit and push changes?

Comment: @TheBigK Yes, that will be a `git push --force` (so make sure to notify any collaborator using that repo), because filter-repo will rewrite the sequence of commits of your local repository. You can first test out that filter on a copy of your local repository, just to check that the overall size is indeed lower after.