# Remove already committed image files from github / Visual Studio git

Tags: visual-studio, github

I have been working on a Net Core project in Visual Studio.

I just realized that all of the image files I have placed in my `wwwroot` folder have been uploaded to my GitHub repository.

I would like to remove these files from the repository but retain them locally in the VS project.
I have created a `.gitignore` file and placed it in the `wwwroot` directory to prevent this from happening again, but am not sure how to remove the files currently uploaded.

I have made several commits since the files were uploaded (but before I realized they were there) so I would prefer not to revert to that point.

Comment: Did you manage to remove those file, as described in my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the new [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) which [replaces  BFG and `git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

Note: if you get the following error message when running the above-mentioned commands:

```
Error: need a version of `git` whose `diff-tree` command has the `--combined-all-paths` option`
```

it means you have to [update `git`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33618/16704).

---

First: do that one copy of your local repo (a new clone)

See "[Path based filtering](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES)":

```
git filter-repo --path file-to-remove --invert-paths
```

At the end, you can (if you are the only one working on that repository) do a `git push --force`

Then restore your files locally.
Since your `.gitignore` is already in place, they won't be added and committed in the future.