# Rewrite git history programatically

Tags: python, git, gitpython, git-rewrite-history

I would like to rewrite the history of one of my repo **programatically**, for example using gitpython.
The idea is to read a existing repository, and reapply each of its commits to a new one, after some modification:

- different commiting time
- splitting some commit to a submodule, if files match some pattern, adding a reference to the submodule commit
- use a different commit message

Using gitpython, I can read the commit history tree and all the relevant informations, but I haven't found a way to commit something on a new repo, no more success when the information must be copied from another repo.

Is there a way to do this programatically?
I imagine there must be a way, as it can be done more or less by hand, one commit by one.

Many thanks!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use gitpython for this? In general, `git-filter-branch` provides a language-agnostic interface you can use from any language at all, including shell.

Comment: No strong reasons, but  I'm not easy with git-filter-branch syntax. I don't see any way of incorporating submodule history while spliting it. I can handle the time change for all commit together, which is very easy for me in python. Basically I would feel much more in control on what I'm doing...

Answer (score 2):

You can take inspiration (or directly use) [`newren/git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), which is:

- written in Python, and
- [replaces BFG or `git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

`git filter-repo` can handle splitting repository, but not necessarily adding in the same step a tree SHA1 as gitlink for a submodule repository.
Still, it can be extended to do what you need.