# Github - Keep only last n versions of large files

Tags: github

Our GitHub repo has grown in size. Cloning on a new machine takes a lot of time and bandwidth. This is mainly because we're keeping JAR files in our repo. I understand we can use something like nexus to place jars.

As a short term fix, is there a way we can keep only last n versions of a file in GitHub?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you might consider activating [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) in order to store only references to your JARs instead of the binary artifacts themselves.

It is possible on GitHub, but [the bandwidth will be limited](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/about-storage-and-bandwidth-usage).

The alternative is to use Instead of BFG, try the [new `git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), which [will replace the old `git filter-branch` or BFG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).
You would need a [commit callback](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#CALLBACKS) which would remove those files if the date is too old.