# How to remove Redis file dump.rdb from Git tracking files

Tags: git, redis

The dump.rdb file accidentally fell into one of the commits and now I can’t remove it from tracking. I am trying this command:

```sh
git rm -r --cached dump.rdb
```

or this

```sh
git rm dump.rdb --cached
```

The result is the same:

```sh
fatal: path specifier “dump.rdb” does not match any file
```

But this file inside my repo:

```sh
ls
Gemfile           app               config.ru         Gemfile.lock      babel.config.js   db 
node_modules      public            yarn.lock         README.md         bin               dump.rdb
config            lib               package.json
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check first if a simple `rm` is enough.

```
rm dump.rb
git status
```

If the status is clean, the file was not part of the commit in the first place.

---

But you could also check if that file was versioned in a *past* commit.
For that, don't use the [obsolete BFG or `git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).
Use new tool [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (directly in your regular local repository, although a backup is always a good idea before those kind of filtering)

Use a [path filtering](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES):

```
git filter-repo --path dump.rb --invert-paths
```

That will remove `dump.rb` from the Git repository history if it was present.