# How to make subfolders repository in Github

Tags: github

I've been using this folder structure where I would have one main .git folder and then have subfolders inside which doesn't have .git folder.

So as example :

```
Main Folder
   Subfolder
   Subfolder
   Subfolder
```

Now what I want to do is, I would like to extract some of those subfolders and make them separate repositories with their histories. Which means subfolders will become a main folder as a repository. Any idea how?

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository) use [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch).

But [that or BFG are obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

Use the new tool [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (directly in your regular local repository, although a backup is always a good idea before those kind of filtering)

Use a [path shorcut](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_path_shortcuts):

```
git filter-repo --subdirectory-filter Subfolder1
```

> Only look at history that touches the given subdirectory and treat that directory as the project root.
>   Equivalent to using --path / --path-rename /: