# .git/objects is bigger then the entire git repo, how to resolve the issue?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I accidentally uploaded some unnecessary files to my git repo. Somehow I deleted all the unnecessary files from the local repo and pushed all the changes forcefully to GitHub, and it worked and all files are completely gone.

However I am facing a strange issue, when I download the git repo through GitHub page using download button the:

```
size of my repo is 500kbs
```

When I clone the repo through git clone, terminal output shows:

```
it dowloaded  around 130MB
```

However, at the end, after download completes (this size seems ok after unzipping the 500kb file):

```
git repo size is around  1.3MB.
```

When I check the property of the directory though UI:

```
it shows 1.3MB
```

When I try to check the property through command prompt(du -sh /Dir):

```
it shows size 130MB
```

I try to explore a bit more then I found that .git/object has the missing big chunk around 130MB.

I am trying to understand what the problem is, and how I can resolve the issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you use `git filter-branch` or `git filter-repo` to delete the unnecessary files from all the commits? If not, the file data are still referred to by the old commits and exist in the git database.

Answer (score 0):

I would first check the result of a purge of the history of your repository: use the new tool [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) which [replaces  BFG and `git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

```
git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M
```

Check the size of the `.git` folder then.
Make sure those large files were not needed in your repo history.

Note: if you get the following error message when running the above-mentioned commands:

```
Error: need a version of `git` whose `diff-tree` command has the `--combined-all-paths` option`
```

it means you have to [update `git`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33618/16704).