# Gitlab repositry mirror to Github

Tags: git, github, gitlab

- I want to create mirror repository from Gitlab to Github, but i encountered an error: **Larger file than Github allow, GH001: Larger files detected** ,i was try using **git filter-branch** to remove file larger size in all commit, rewrite commit history,success but after that, i get error (in image)
- Any idea or keyword, please give me.Thanks!

[image: Error mirror repository Gitlab]

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use the [new `git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), which [will replace the old `git filter-branch` or BFG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).
Stripping large/big files is easy

```
 git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M
```

Second, `git filter-branch`/`git filter-repo` is a local operation: you still need to force push (git push --force --mirror) to GitLab, in order for your mirror operation to reflect the new repository state (one without large files)

Comment: thank for reply, i was run `git filter-branch` and push --force success to Gitlab, image above is error after i push success `git filter-branch`

Comment: @Hydraw Is it possible that you have cleaned up/pushed only master, and other large files exist in other branches?

Comment: I checked, all branch is not exsist large file

Comment: @Hydraw Are you pushing to gitlab.com? Did you do a `git push --force --mirror`, in order to push *all* branches?

Comment: Currently, because error so my mirror (Github) not yet created (empty) so i think i don't necessary to run git command above, right?

Comment: So how do you get your error message? Is it from GitLab.com?

Comment: Ahh,i think error from Github, and Gitlab show it, error message show when i try to create mirror repository from Gitlab to Github

Comment: in message error , u can see something like `/data/github/releases/...`