# Removing a file in Git repo but file doesn't exist

Tags: angularjs, github, git-lfs

In committing and pushing to my repo, I get the following error:
[image]

The issue is that I've already manually deleted the video file. The video does not exist anywhere in my repo.
I also tried to
`git rm src/assets/video/Greensleeves` and it says `fatal: pathspec src/assets/video/Greensleeves did not match any files`.

How can I get passed this so that I can commit/push?

[image]

Comment: it must have been added in a previous commit but then deleted in a later one, you'll have to rebase out the commit that has that large file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and apply the [new `git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), which [does replace the old `git filter-branch` or BFG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

It has [many usage examples](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES), including path-based filtering, in order for you to remote the `src/assets/video/Greensleeves` file in past commits:

> To keep all files except these paths, just add `--invert-paths`:
>
> ```
> git filter-repo --path src/assets/video/Greensleeves --invert-paths
> ```

Then `git push --force` (that does rewrite the history of your repository, so make sure to notify any other collaborator)

Since it must be done on a fresh clone:

1. Don't touch anything to your current clone folder
2. Create a separate clone of the repository, where you do the filter repo
3. In that second clone, now cleaned (no more big file in its history), import your work from your first repo

That is, for point 3:

```sh
cd /path/to/second/clone
git --work-tree=/path/to/first/original/clone add .
git commit -m "Import work from first clone"
git push --force
```

Comment: I added another screenshot with the console message from ```git filter-repo```

Comment: @DeAnnaMartinez OK: do it on a fresh clone of your repository.

Comment: I have added so much to my repo but haven't been able to commit in over a week, so if I clone, it will be missing code and then I can just copy/paste in my new code?

Comment: @DeAnnaMartinez I have edited my answer to address your comment/question.