# Access GitHub Secret Key

Tags: github, secret-key

I'm lost as to how to handle secret keys.

I've published a repo on GitHub with a secret key (I know now, big no no), then found out about the GitHub Secret Key in the settings and stored the key there.

So, two questions:

- what's the best way to clean the commit history so that the secret key isn't available anymore?
- how do I actually access this secret key? In my settings.py, I now had `SECRET_KEY = 'name_of_key_on_github'` but that throws `NameError: not defined`.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

**Update**

Ok, so according to the link provided by @VonC, I need to create a .yml file in `.github/workflows` directory.

**general.yml**

```
name: key #needed but name can be arbitrary

on: [push, pull_request, deployment]

env:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      - uses: actions/labeler@v2
        with:
          repo-token: ${{ secrets.name_of_my_key }}
      credentials: #these don't work yet, if anyone can tell me why?
        username: ${{ github.actor }}
        password: ${{ secrets.ghcr_token }}
```

**settings.py**

`SECRET_KEY = "../.github/general.yml"`

**Project structure** if you want / need to reproduce:

```
myrepo
├── app_name
│   ├── settings.py
├── .github
│   ├── workflows
│   │   ├── general.yml
```

I can run `python manage.py runserver`, but on pushing to remote I get the following error:

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (refusing to allow a Personal Access Token to create or update workflow `.github/workflows/general.yml` without `workflow` scope)
```

**Update 2**

Hadn't enabled the workflow scope (github.com > profile > settings > developer settings > personal access tokens):

You need to make sure box is checked.

[image: workflow box needs to be checked]

Comment: So why don't you add the workflow scope? (https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps)

Comment: @VonC - that was the problem! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Great! I have edited my answer to add that step.

Comment: I'm still not clear on the credentials, ubuntu keeps prompting me for them - shouldn't they be automatic with what I added in the .yml?

Comment: Which ubuntu? Yours (local machine) Or the GitHb Action VM?

Comment: On my local machine - might that have to do something with the link I used to clone?

Comment: Local means check your `git config credential.helper`: its credential helper might have cached the old credentials.

Comment: Again, worked a charm! Followed this link: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials

Comment: Well done! That should do it indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [new `git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), which [does replace the old `git filter-branch` or BFG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

It has [many usage examples](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES), including content-based filtering, in order for you to remote the `path/to/secret` file in past commits:

> To keep all files except these paths, just add `--invert-paths`:
>
> ```
> git filter-repo --path path/to/secret --invert-paths
> ```

You can add `--dry-run` to test it before actually changing your repository.

Then `git push --force` (that does rewrite the history of your repository, so make sure to notify any other collaborator)

Since it must be done on a fresh clone:

1. Don't touch anything to your current clone folder
2. Create a separate clone of the repository, where you do the filter repo
3. In that second clone, now cleaned (no more big file in its history), import your work from your first repo

That is, for point 3:

```sh
cd /path/to/second/clone
git --work-tree=/path/to/first/original/clone add .
git commit -m "Import work from first clone"
git push --force
```

Regarding git gilter-repo, see a complete example in "[Removing sensitive files from git](https://boopathi.blog/removing-sensitive-files-from-git/) from [Boopathi Rajaa](https://twitter.com/heisenbugger).

---

You can store encrypted keys, but available for [GitHub Actions only](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets).

Outside of GitHub Actions, see [Github, secret keys and other local settings](https://pythoneatstail.com/en/overview-all-articles/github-secret-keys-and-other-local-settings/) from [Paul Smits](https://pythoneatstail.com/en/about/).

For that you need a credential (PAT) [with workflow scope](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps).

Comment: Hi @VonC, thank you for your help. Let me double check and see if I got that all.

1. I clone my repo from github to a second location.
2. Change the worktree to original location
3. Use ```filter-repo```
4. force push to original repo

Do I understand correctly that both locations point to the same repo on Github? Do I get rid of the original repo afterwards?

Comment: Ok, so I followed the article you linked by Boopathi Rajaa. I did ```git filter-repo --invert-paths``` and I can see the new files in .git. But when I ```git push --force```, my remote is disconnected:
```fatal: No configured push destination.```

I've tried ```git add remote repo_name repo_link``` and get nothing back.

What do you suggest?

Comment: @LisaLaw If your local repository is correct (meaning it has its full history, and the sensitive information is gone), you need to add the remote back (which you did), and then `git push -u origin master` (assuming the default branch is `master`, and not `main`, like it is the case for new repositories these days)

Comment: Great, this seems to have worked. Do I have to do all my pushes like this now or can I go back to ```git push``` on its own?

Comment: @LisaLaw No, the next push (from the default `master` branch) will be a simple `git push`

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much for all your help. :) I think I've got all my doubts cleared now, hehe. At least for this question ;)

Comment: @LisaLaw Great! Well done. Until your next question, then.