# How to undo the changes in github after deleting a file?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, git-pull

Today I raised a PR (from my IDE): inside that, 3 files have been touch, in the commit I pushed.

Now what I did: I deleted one file's in GitHub and created a new commit (file changed is 2 now) .

Can you please help me to revert/undo the deletion of the file?

(I am very new to Git versioning system & GitHub.com)

Comment: You need to provide more details. Which branch did you delete the file from ? Did you delete the file from another branch and then merge via Pull Request (in this case you can [revert the Pull Request](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.0/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/reverting-a-pull-request)) or you just deleted from master/main branch and directly committed on the master/main ?

Comment: I edited your message trying to make it clearer and to correct the use the technical terms. I tried my best, but please verify that the meaning has been preserved.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I understood you did:
*(even though you might have done it only via the GitHub.com GUI)*

```
git add file1 file2 file3
git commit -m 'add files'
rm file1
git add file1
git commit -m 'removed unnecessary file'
git push origin master
```

now you want to restore the `file1`, right?

If yes, you can prepare via:

- `git stash -u` to temporary remove all non-committed changes.
- `git checkout master` to ensure you are in the same branch you want to restore the file into (can also use `git log` and `git show HEAD` to see you last commits)

Then…

## …to actually restore the `file1` you can:

- `git revert HEAD` and confirm; this will create a new commit that restores all the changes brought from the last commit (`HEAD`). This is effectively like an **undo** operation, that will be visible in your Git history (again, see `git log`)

or

- instead of restoring the whole previous commit, you can **checkout** (restore) only the specific `file1`, **from a commit** back in the history (`HEAD` is the *current/last commit*, while `HEAD^` is *one commit back in time*, `HEAD^^^` is *3 commit back in time*; you can see its changes with `git show HEAD^`)

  - `git checkout HEAD^ -- file1`  to restore the file (see the created change via `git diff`)
  - `git add file1` & `git commit -m 'restore the file that was wrongly removed'` in order to re-add the file and re-commit it.
  - `git push origin master --force-with-lease` to **overwrite** the previous commit

    - **BEWARE: THIS IS STRONGLY DISCOURAGED!** Especially if you don't have A LOT of confidence with Git. Forcing a `git push` has the potential to ERASE FOREVER ALL THE WORK YOU DID ON A PROJECT. So please, **avoid this option**, and check it again in the future. You can also give a check to [this old question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720268/git-commands-that-could-break-rewrite-the-history).

---

## Additionally

I have the impression that you do not have clear what is the difference between ***Git*** (a protocol and a versioning system managed via console) and ***GitHub.com*** (the Microsoft online portal to store, manage, display *Git repositories*).

The interface provided from GitHub.com is **extremely limited**, so you cannot perform the operation of `revert` only via the GitHub.com user interface.

Unfortunately you will have to learn how to manage Git via CLI (Command Line Interface). It is a pain in the beginning, but it is well worth the effort (if you are a developer).
Using one Git GUI Client (see [this list](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis)) might help a lot while you try to understand Git, its commands and its logic.

**PS** - Don't forget to mark this as best answer, with the ✅, if this clarifies your doubts.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer and explanation, I raised a PR from the vs code, I am explaining the steps what I did, I create one branch  inside that I did only two file changes but I don't know why previous branch changes also reflected into the git then it becomes 3files changed in git PR, in the GitHub I deleted a file-3 but now I need to  revert back
Steps what I did in viscode:-1) git checkout 2)createNew branch3)commit message 4)select a tick mark In vs code 5)git push
Steps I did in GitHub:-1) click on PR 2)select file changes 3)click on file 3 and delete 4) from vscode I did git pull

Comment: When you create a new branch, this is based on the current branch (so when you create a `PR-branch`  from `branch-1`, you are at the same point in the Git history (you are only using a different pointer now, called `PR-branch`). When you create a commit on `PR-branch` this becomes the same as *[ history of `branch-1`, plus 1 commit pointed by `PR-branch`]*. **E.g.** of your history:  INIT-commit <-- FIRST-commit (master) <-- SECOND-commit (branch-1) <-- THIRD-commit (PR-branch) <-- FOURTH-commit (commit to revert the changes from SECOND-commit). Tell me if I am wrong, it's not easy to guess.

Comment: If that's correct, then I think your mistake was to **base the `PR-branch` onto the history of `branch-1`**, instead of basing `PR-branch` onto the history of `master` branch (so `PR-branch` derails from the history of `branch-1`).