# How can I diff a repo before and after filter branch?

Tags: git, diff, git-filter-branch

Git has an advanced command called filter branch for making various complex changes to a repo's git history. I intend to use this to fix some accidental mistakes in my repo, but I'm not experienced with it and I want to make sure I don't accidentally do something wrong.

Once I apply my git filter branch command(s), I will end up with a new repository that has the git history altered. I'd like to compare it to the one before filter branch to make sure that exactly those changes I intended have been made.

By doing a simple recursive diff, I can check that the *final state* of the repo is as expected. But what about the history? If I diff the `.git` directory, I suspect it won't be much help. What else can I do to see which commits differ between two repos, across all branches?

Answer (score 2):

First, do a filter operation on a separate clone, in order to easily go back to the original state if needed.

Plus, you will be able to do a `git log` in each repository, for comparison.

Second, consider using [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) instead of the [obsolete `git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

Comment: So are you suggesting I simply `diff` the `git log` output for either repo?

Comment: @Wassinger Exactly, that seems one easy way to see the changes. Omit the SHA in your git log command, since those will differ anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you will have all your commits (both pre- and post- `filter-branch` / `filter-repo`) in the same repository.

You can check your reflog, spot the relevant commits, and use these with `git log` or `git diff`.

You can use the per-branch reflog to scan a shorter list of commits :

```
git reflog target/branch

# you can either use the shas listed in the reflog,
# or the '@{xx}' references mentioned next to them :
git log --graph --oneline target/branch@{3} target/branch
```