# Ignore specific files when resolving conflicts when rebasing

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

I have checked out a very old feature branch and would like to rebase master.

However, there are webpack build files that aren't included in .gitignore which causes the rebase to prompt me to resolve conflicts for every commit of the feature branch for these webpack build files.

My question is, is there a way to ignore these webpack build files conflicts?

Comment: Not really, no. You could write a *merge driver* that uses `theirs` (not `-X theirs`, just `theirs`) , which would mostly kinda sorta work sometimes, and use your `.git/info/attributes` file to call it up. But since it only kinda sorta works, and then only sometimes, it's still the wrong way to go.

Comment: The *right* way to go (rather more painful of course) is to rewrite history so that there are no committed build files.  Then the problem never comes up in the first place, and the repository doesn't grow fat with build products either. But if the pain is too great and you want to attempt the merge driver method, search for "git merge driver theirs".

Comment: How many commits are there? Can you re-generate the generated files? Then you could simply do `regenerate; git add file; git rebase --continue` a bunch of times.

Answer (score 0):

> The right way to go (rather more painful of course) is to rewrite history so that there are no committed build files.

Considering the branch's history will be rewritten anyway, once rebased on top of master, filtering its content first is a viable option.

Use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), which replaces  [`BFG` and `git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309). Note: [Install it first](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md).

Before proceeding, make sure you have a complete backup of your repository.

Use `git filter-repo` to remove the webpack build files from your branch's history. Replace `path/to/webpack/build/files/*` with the actual path to your webpack build files.

```bash
git filter-repo --path path/to/webpack/build/files/* --invert-paths
```

After running the command, check your repository's history to make sure the files have been removed.

If you have already pushed the branch with the build files to a remote repository, you will need to force push your changes. Coordinate with anyone else who may be using the same branch (but, since it is a very old branch, chances are, nobody is using it at the moment).

```bash
git push origin <branch-name> --force
```

Now that the build files are removed from the history, you can proceed with rebasing onto master:

```bash
git rebase master
```